# How to accomplish drop down word suggestions in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, drop-down-menu, autocomplete, qlineedit

Say I have 10 names in a `QListWidget` (which is hidden) and an a `QLineEdit`. Now if I type the letter "a" in the line Edit it should display a drop down of all those name in the list widget that begin with the letter "A". the user could select using a mouse or a keyboard (since there will be a vertical scroll-bar). I am not sure if a `QLineEdit` could do this. But I would like to know what is out there to accomplish this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `QCompleter` which provides a way for autocompletion in widgets like `QLineEdit` and `QComboBox`. When the user starts typing a word, `QCompleter` suggests possible ways of completing the word, based on a word list.

An example from the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#basic-usage):

```
QStringList wordList;
wordList << "alpha" << "omega" << "omicron" << "zeta";

QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

Comment: Thanks Ill give this a try and post back

Comment: You don't even need to populate the `QCompleter` with data manually, you can just pass the model that your `QListWidget` is already using by calling the `QAbstractItemView::model()` function.

Comment: I lot more straightforward and to the point than the QtProject example. Thanks.

Comment: Nix that.  The QCompleter page actually gives this very example.  My bad.