# Qt: shows the possibilities while typing into lineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to make some kind of "help" to the users in my program.
There is a `QLineEdit` inside, and I would like to do the following: During they are typing, the program will show them the possibilities after their text (for example with a blue background) For instance: You can type in only 4 names: Anne, Peter, Matthew, Angela. When the user at "An", there will be "gela" after his text, and if he presses the `Left button` it will be written "Angela". Is it possible? (It would show the suggestions like when you start to typing a link in the google chrome search bar, without the dropdown list) [image]

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248606/how-to-accomplish-drop-down-word-suggestions-in-qt

Comment: Well, I want to make it without the dropdown list, only with the highlighted suggestion, like on the picture: the guy wrote "you", and he got a suggestion "tube.com/"

Comment: In the answer is the QCompleter class mentioned. I am sure you can customize it for your desired behavior

Comment: Yeah I just looked: it has "completion modes" so this should be to your hearts desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a helper class for that QCompleter : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qcompleter.html