# Parse JSON Array with Qt

Tags: c++, json, qt, api, dictionary

I'm trying to write a desktop client with Qt for an [online dictionary site](http://tureng.com/). I got stuck on something about JSON.

http://ac.tureng.co/?c=?&t=expensive

```
?(["expensive","expensive habits","expensive medical equipment","expensive question","expensive watch","expensive-looking","expensively","expensiveness"]);
```

I think the data which come from the above address is JSON array. json.org has the following description:

> An array is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with [
>   (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).[*](https://www.json.org/)

Also a valid JSON according to the [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) if a string is written instead of the first question mark:

```
a([  
   "expensive",
   "expensive habits",
   "expensive medical equipment",
   "expensive question",
   "expensive watch",
   "expensive-looking",
   "expensively",
   "expensiveness"
]);
```

But this change is not enough for the [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) site:

```
["expensive", "expensive habits", "expensive medical equipment", "expensive question", "expensive watch", "expensive-looking", "expensively", "expensiveness"]
```

I want to show suggestions to the user at the user input using the data from here. For now I can't extract JSON, so I've reached the desired behavior by acting it as plain text. Is there a way to do this properly by parsing JSON?

The codes I've written so far are:

```
    QString turengOneriMetin = QString("http://ac.tureng.co/?c=?&t=%1").arg(arg1);
    QUrl turengOneri(turengOneriMetin);

    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(turengOneri));
    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response, SIGNAL(finished()), &event, SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();
    QString content = response->readAll();

    content.replace(0,1,"a");

    content = content.replace("a([", "").replace("]);", "").replace("\"","");


    QStringList wordList;

    wordList << content.split(",");

    ui->label->setText(content);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24248606/how-to-accomplish-drop-down-word-suggestions-in-qt
    QCompleter *completer = new QCompleter(wordList, this);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    ui->lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

**Update:** After receiving the JSON correctly with help of answers and [other resources](https://forum.qt.io/topic/88203/how-to-process-json-array-with-qjsonxxx/5) I've done what I wanted with the following piece of code:

```
QJsonDocument document = QJsonDocument::fromJson(content.toUtf8());
QJsonArray documentArray = document.array();

QStringList wordList;

for (const QJsonValue &i : documentArray)
{
    //qInfo() << i.toString() << endl;
    wordList << i.toString();
}
```

Comment: Does this site have some kind of API doc? I wouldn't go too far down the rabbit hole of assuming this is JSON format without validating that.

Comment: why `?c` in your url?

Comment: @MrEricSir there's no API doc available. But in GitHub someone can see how similar clients uses the API.

Comment: @eyllanesc you're right, it's useless here and without it, link gives a valid JSON. I'm going to check to see whether I can parse this result.

Answer (score 0):

I think that URL should be this - http://ac.tureng.co/?t=expensive

In this case you'll get valid JSON.